# API Call: returning observable<object>

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create a function that returns an Observable. I'm using the following API (https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/).

My model:

```
export class Pokemon {
id: number;
name: string;
height: number;
  weight: number;
  types: PokemonType[];
  image_url: string;
  shiny_url: string;
}

export class PokemonType {
  slot: number;
  name: string;
}
```

I've tried. However the code below returns a normal Pokemon and I would like to return an Observable so that I can use the subscribe function.

```
export class PokemonService {
  API_ADDRESS: string = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private toastService: ToastService) { }


getPokemon(id: number) : Pokemon {
    var result: Pokemon = new Pokemon();
    this.httpClient.get<any>(`${this.API_ADDRESS}/${id}`).subscribe(pokemon => {
      result.id = pokemon.id;
      result.image_url = pokemon.sprites.front_default;
    });
    return result;
  }
}
```

I found a bunch of websites that are trying to explain API calls, however some are outdated and I don't need all the data from the API just the variables mentioned in the class.

Who can help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way

```
getPokemon(id: number) : observable<Pokemon>{

   return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${this.API_ADDRESS}/${id}`).pipe(map(pokemon => {
      var result: Pokemon = new Pokemon();
      result.id = pokemon.id;
      result.image_url = pokemon.sprites.front_default;
      return result; // 
    }));

  }
```

now you just need to subscribe to `getPokemon`

**Updated!**

In case or error handling we can use rxjs `catch / catchError`

```
  getPokemon(id: number) {

    return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${this.API_ADDRESS}/${id}`).pipe(
      map(pokemon => {
        var result: Pokemon = new Pokemon();
        result.id = pokemon.id;
        result.image_url = pokemon.sprites.front_default;
        return result; // 
      }),
      catchError(error => throwError(error))
    );

  }
```

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-http-error-handling)

check this [RxJs Error Handling: Complete Practical Guide](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/)

Comment: I've tried this, but I get this error: 

[ng] ERROR in src/app/api/pokemon.service.ts(23,66): error TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.

I read that u need to use pipe, but i don't know how.

Comment: it works, thanks! How can I add error handling? Do you need get<any> or get<Pokemon>

Comment: you can use catchError operator https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html

Comment: if I use the catchError operator, I get the following error: ERROR in src/app/api/pokemon.service.ts(20,5): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<any[] | Pokemon>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Pokemon>'.
[ng]   Type 'any[] | Pokemon' is not assignable to type 'Pokemon'.
[ng]     Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'Pokemon'.
[ng]       Property 'id' is missing in type 'any[]'. Code: https://pastebin.com/ZHfpsHPV

Comment: I have update the answer and add an example of handling the errors 